# Роутинг в табах и по страничный роутинг

Tags: angularjs

Не работает роутинг, больше всего интересует роутинг в табах, очень мало примеров и нет четких инструкций
[Пример кода](http://embed.plnkr.co/NC0MQfgrzXmHcvsHWLWE/)

```
var app = angular.module('Plunker', ['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap'])
app.config([
    '$stateProvider',
    '$urlRouterProvider',
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        $stateProvider
        .state('homepage', {
            url: "/homepage",
            templateUrl: "homepage/homepage.html"
        })
        .state('myportfolio', {
                url: "/myportfolio",
                templateUrl: "myportfolio/my-portfolio.html"
            })
        .state('services', {
            url: "",
            views: {
              "tab1": { templateUrl: "tab1.html" },
              "tab2": { templateUrl: "tab2.html" },
              "tab3": { templateUrl: "tab3.html" },
            }
          })
          .state('contacts', {
            url: "/contacts",
            templateUrl: "contacts/contacts.html"
        })

    }]);

app.controller('tabsController', function($rootScope, $scope, $state){
    $scope.tabs = [
        {title: "Разработка и доработка сайтов", route: "tab1",  active: true},
        {title: "Редизайн и реверстка CMS", route: "tab2", active: false},
        {title: "Участие в разработке SPA", route: "tab3", active: false}
    ]

});
```